# Elasticsearch network discovery integration

Tags: elasticsearch, networking

iam new to elasticsearch, i had deployed elasticsearch with kibana and logstash, all the logs is parsed and searchable. i need to integrate any software that helps in network descovery to find the devices on my network.
what is the best integration found that can help me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is going to be pretty generic, as you haven't provided any information about your specific requirements / technical constraints / budget / ...

here are some well-established discovery tools that you can integrate with Elasticsearch to find devices on your network:

- [Nmap](https://nmap.org/): popular open-source network exploration and security auditing tool. You can export its results in various formats, including JSON, which can be ingested into Elasticsearch.
- [OpenNMS](https://www.opennms.com/): a network management platform that includes a discovery engine for identifying devices on the network and monitoring their performance/status. OpenNMS can also integrate with Elasticsearch ([docs](https://docs.opennms.com/horizon/30/operation/elasticsearch/introduction.html)).
- [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/): another network monitoring platform that includes a discovery feature for finding devices on the network automatically. Zabbix can also integrate with Elasticsearch ([docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/appendix/install/elastic_search_setup), not too updated)

Comment: thanks, man  iam trying to work with zero budget, to build a complete SIEM, so for that am looking for opensource tools to integrate with elastic search the community version.

Comment: I will try the Nmap since I can save the output to a file and then ingest it to elasticsearch to build the dashboard accordingly. 
thank you I am grateful